How to extend / partition by reducing /home partition in a live linux server?
We are running a CentOS Linux server to host websites. The website data are stored in /home partition and it is mounted separately.
Here's it:
[root@myserver ~]# df -h
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                     63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        63G  5.2M   63G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        63G  4.0G   59G   7% /run
tmpfs                        63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/almalinux-root   70G   43G   28G  61% /
none                         63G  6.5M   63G   1% /var/lve/dbgovernor-shm
/dev/nvme0n1p2             1014M  352M  663M  35% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1              599M  5.8M  594M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/almalinux-home  1.8T  185G  1.6T  11% /home
[root@myserver ~]#

A few days ago the / partition (/dev/mapper/almalinux-root) got 100% full because of apache logs in /var/log/apache2 and this created a lot of issues in the application. We removed the apache log archives and it was fixed, but now we are thinking to allocate 130GB more to the / partition making it 200GB by reducing /home.
However /home partition contains very important data of our websites, though we took the backups but loss of data would be dangerous as restoring is pretty hard and time taking.
We are using LVM. Here's:
pvdisplay:
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/nvme0n1p3
  VG Name               almalinux
  PV Size               <1.82 TiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              476525
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          476525
  PV UUID               HFApEz-360o-PObM-ZTQd-QHu9-dkqZ-4YF2tq

vgdisplay:
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               almalinux
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <1.82 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              476525
  Alloc PE / Size       476525 / <1.82 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               IvUACo-HCqk-MWAn-fXwO-VN8l-Td2J-nA0B6Y

lvdisplay:
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/almalinux/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                almalinux
  LV UUID                sCooVi-Bdyx-2d0n-7cQ2-wUHs-riB0-1INAS1
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2024-01-06 16:05:01 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                4.00 GiB
  Current LE             1024
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/almalinux/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                almalinux
  LV UUID                ea94Lx-KVcI-hofd-PQlK-jQ1C-tpzf-utH3vY
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2024-01-06 16:05:01 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                <1.75 TiB
  Current LE             457581
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/almalinux/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                almalinux
  LV UUID                t2o4rg-GQX0-vNGx-IuqT-OIcR-tjhn-JZN2m1
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost.localdomain, 2024-01-06 16:05:09 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                70.00 GiB
  Current LE             17920
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:0

lsblk -l:
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
almalinux-root 253:0    0   70G  0 lvm  /
almalinux-swap 253:1    0    4G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
almalinux-home 253:2    0  1.8T  0 lvm  /home
nvme0n1        259:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
nvme0n1p1      259:1    0  600M  0 part /boot/efi
nvme0n1p2      259:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
nvme0n1p3      259:3    0  1.8T  0 part

/etc/fstab:
/dev/mapper/almalinux-root      /       xfs     defaults,uquota 0       0
UUID=361a5ed8-c8cc-455a-8a82-2ae909ad10d4 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=E165-D687          /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 2
/dev/mapper/almalinux-home      /home   xfs     defaults,uquota 0       0
/dev/mapper/almalinux-swap none                    swap    defaults        0 0
/usr/tmpDSK             /tmp                    ext4    defaults,noauto        0 0

What we want to do is basically reduce 130GB from /home partition and then add 130GB to the / partition. The /home partition is a xfs partition and contains very serious data, so we want to do it without losing data. We are running cPanel on the system and the /home contains all the data of the cPanels which is very crucial.
So we would like to ask suggestion and command which should be used to perform this operation.
Thank you.

(this should be a comment, but its a bit long)

the / partition ... got 100% full because of apache logs

You have multiple partitions but you put the webserver logs on what is primarily a webserver in '/' ? Why?

/home partition contains very important data of our websites

Why?

almalinux-root 253:0    0   70G  0 lvm  /

So....not a Centos installation?
This server is considered "important" / you can't afford any downtime but the storage is only a single NMVE device?

Apache logs are saved in /var/log/apache2/ folder which is in / partition. We can create a new partition for that as well but still we have to shrink /home.
The /home partition contains very important because there are websites, there are many websites hosted on the server and they are important because it takes time to build websites.
It's a AlmaLinux installation.
The server has a single NVMe Device because that is what it needed.

Please go read up best practice for configuring Linux systems and basic systems admin. If you cannot afford downtime on this you cannot afford to be running it off a single disk. And your current partitioning is far from best practice. Indeed its so far away from the state it should be in, and given your uptime requirement you should just start afresh on its replacement.
